# Correct way to degrade gracefully?

Tags: css, html, graceful-degradation

I have a HTML 5 drag and drop game that doesn't work in IE so I want to basically just show the answers in the form of an image. At the moment I'm using CSS to hide the game `div` in IE and display a `div` with using `display: block;` to show the image and hide it using `display: none` on browsers like Chrome.

Is this an ok way of switching content based on browser or is there another method I should be looking at? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: If it's just drag-and-drop, it should work in IE5.5, since Microsoft basically added that feature to the Internet (like they did `innerHTML`). So you must be doing something wrong. Post a link and I can take a look and tell you why it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: These days I tend to think that the best way to degrade gracefully in IE is to just tell people to upgrade their browser.

Comment: You're better off showing us a demo and including the problem code in your question content, than necessarily self-diagnosing (as @Kolink suggests). If you can, make a http://jsfiddle.net demo with your code so we can look at it in action.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have managed to get the drag and drop working on IE now. I mainly wanted to know is using display:none etc and ok way to degrade i.e. is it acceptable because surely the content is loading but just hiding this way?

Comment: How are you manipulating the `div`s `display`? Are you using an IE conditional to include an extra snippet of CSS? As it stands, this seems too vague to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only draggable elements in IE are the `<a>` and `<img>` elements.

Some people just wrap their (text) content with `<a>` tags that go nowhere, as is seen in Remy Sharp's demo: http://html5demos.com/drag. This works just fine in IE9, and probably older versions of IE.

So the "correct" way to handle IE is to use those elements.

Comment: The `a` elements have to go *somewhere* for them to work in IE, but it is OK for that somewhere to be `#`.  Just remember to cancel the `onclick`.